# (Nuxt.js) Firebase error when using Nuxt.js on top of Vue.js, but works fine with vanilla Vue.js

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, nuxt.js

I made a website with pure Vue.js, everything works fine.

However, I transferred the project to Nuxt.js, after setting up "everything", I get this error in the development page:

```
Firebase: Firebase App named '[DEFAULT]' already exists (app/duplicate-app).
```

Here's the firebase file ('fb.js') which I used to export the database:

"fb.js" (Root folder)

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/firestore'

// Initialize Firebase
var config = {
    apiKey: "KEY",
    authDomain: "DOMAIN",
    databaseURL: "DBURL",
    projectId: "PID",
    storageBucket: "SBUCKET",
    messagingSenderId: "MSID"
};

firebase.initializeApp(config);

const db = firebase.firestore();

db.settings({timestampsInSnapshots: true})

export default db;
```

"component.vue" (Components folder) *This code is not exactly the same as my files, but the key parts are here

```
<template>

<div class="allprojects" v-for="(project, key) in projects" :key="key">
<span> {{project.title}} </span>
<span> {{project.person}} </span>
<span> {{project.due_date}} </span>
<span> {{project.status}} </span>
</div>

</template>

<script>
import db from '@/fb.js';

export default {


data() {
    return {
        projects: []
    },
created() {
        db.collection('projects').onSnapshot(res => {
            const changes = res.docChanges();

            changes.forEach(change => {
                if (change.type === 'added') {
                    this.projects.push({
                        ...change.doc.data(),
                        id: change.doc.id
            })
          }

}
</script>
```

"package.json" (Nuxt.js)

```
{
  "name": "web",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Nuxt.js + Vuetify.js project",
  "author": "Alexsander Bispo <35003248+Lexszin@users.noreply.github.com>",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nuxt",
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "start": "nuxt start",
    "generate": "nuxt generate"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "date-fns": "^1.30.1",
    "firebase": "^5.9.2",
    "nuxt": "^2.2.0",
    "vuetify": "^1.3.6",
    "vuetify-loader": "^1.0.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-imports": "^1.5.1",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^12.0.0",
    "eslint-loader": "^2.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-html": "^4.0.6",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.14.0",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^7.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^4.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "^4.0.0",
    "stylus": "^0.54.5",
    "stylus-loader": "^3.0.2"
  },
  "main": ".eslintrc.js",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

"package.json" (Vue.js)

```
{
  "name": "tify",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "date-fns": "^1.30.1",
    "firebase": "^5.9.2",
    "vue": "^2.6.6",
    "vue-router": "^3.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^3.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^3.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^3.5.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
    "eslint": "^5.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^5.0.0",
    "postcss": "^7.0.14",
    "stylus": "^0.54.5",
    "stylus-loader": "^3.0.2",
    "vue-cli-plugin-vuetify": "^0.5.0",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.21",
    "vuetify": "^1.5.8",
    "vuetify-loader": "^1.0.5"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/essential",
      "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "rules": {},
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "babel-eslint"
    }
  },
  "postcss": {
    "plugins": {
      "autoprefixer": {}
    }
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not ie <= 8"
  ]
}
```

As mentioned in the title, this works fine with the vanilla Vue.js, but when built with Nuxt.js, I get this error...

Comment: you should put your fb.js in the plugins folder and import it into nuxt.config.js like this `plugins: [ '~/plugins/fb' ],`

Comment: Just did it, and linked to the plugin in the components as "~/plugins/fb.js", now I get this error: `Function Firestore.settings() requires its first argument to be of type object, but it was: a custom Object object `. Did I do something wrong, or is there something else I need to do?

Comment: Nevermind - the `Function Firestore.settings() requires its first argument to be of type object, but it was: a custom Object object` error happens everytime the page is load for the first time, if I reload the page, the previous error happens again

Comment: Ok, the app is already initialised. try `if (!firebase.apps.length){firebase.initializeApp(config)}`.

Comment: Now I get the error I mentioned `Function Firestore.settings() requires its first argument to be of type object, but it was: a custom Object object`, and it doesn't go away after reloading the page, as it did previously.

Comment: By the way - I don't have any other files accessing the firebase directly, except for accessing it through the "db" variable.

Comment: so it seems it doesn't like this object: `{timestampsInSnapshots: true}`. Maybe try `var ts = new Object();ts.timestampsInSnapshots = true; db.settings(ts)`

Comment: I get the same error, if I remove the settings it works fine... But if the settings are the problem, how will I be able to change them? Also, sorry if these questions are pretty basic, I just started learning JavaScript 1.5~ month(s) ago, and 1.5 Week(s) for Vue, so I'm relatively new to this... One thing I don't understand is - If the problem is the settings line, then why it works without issues on vanilla Vue, and not on Nuxt...? I can't find answers to this specific issue on the internet